# JS - Why can't the Chrome console access my global variable?

Tags: javascript, scope, console, console.log

I have the following variable declared at the top level of the script:

```
var region = “southwest”;
```

When running

```
console.log(region)
```

I'm getting the following error:

VM1094:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: region is not defined
at :1:13

Not sure what is causing this given the variable is global.

Comment: Is the script actually a module?

Comment: Yes, it’s a module. I set it up that way to use async funcions from other modules.

Comment: Modules create a "private" namespace, when you declare a variable in the body of a module, it's not global, it's local to the namespace the module is bound to.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

when you have global variables they will be assigned to window object , in your console try console.log(window.region)

Comment: I tried this and now it’s showing undefined, but the variable is defined. I tried this with other variables that clearly have a value and for some reason got the same result.

Comment: I know it's not good but a picture of your code would be helpfull

Answer (score -1):

Is "southwest" a string or a variable that you have assigned to the 'region' variable?
If it's a string, you need to put it inside the "double quotes".
And, if it is a variable, then you need to assign some value to it.

Comment: Add request for clarification or question in a comment under the question, answer only when you understand the question or the person asking has edited their question for clarity.

Comment: southwest is the value assigned to the variable, for some reason when I pasted here it dropped the “” enclosure, but it does have it in my code.

Comment: Could you add the whole code that you're trying to run? Because in these two statements there is no problem and it runs correctly, so I cannot help you.